# How to use Crashlytics in UNNotificationServiceExtension?

Tags: ios, swift, ios10, crashlytics, ios-extensions

Good day,

Does **Crashlytics** support iOS10's [`UNNotificationServiceExtension`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/usernotifications/unnotificationserviceextension)?

Noticed that service extension is being terminate occasionally (not a timeout) and having hard time getting logs out of it.

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried adding Crashlytics to your extension?  Or are you having a problem with it not working?

Comment: I'm curious how you tried to integrate it. Did you add it to a podfile or something?